# Can I get a local notification when location changes and my app is in background?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, core-location

I'm new in iphone apps and i want to know that how can i get local notification when location changes, and application is running in background.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, although only on the newest hardware (iPhone 4 at this time). Check the documentation for significant location change tracking and region monitoring. The [Location Awareness Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a great start.

Comment: thanks Ortwin Gentz. you mean that, by calling  startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges ,i get a local notification..

Comment: @user621147, not directly. You'll receive the usual CLLocationManager delegate callback while your app is running in the background. From that method you can create a local notification.

Comment: would u please send a sample code to me bçoz i'm so confused. thanks